# capybara click an item based upon text AND html data attributes

Tags: rspec, capybara

I've used capybara with rspec / rails for really simple tests but have a page with a lot of buttons. I have a set of buttons like this:

```
<button class="add-item text-as-link btn" data-menu-item-id="50" data-menu-header-id="34">add menu item</button>
```

The data-menu-item-id would probably be as specific as I need. How would I do:

```
click_on "add menu item"  # need to also have data-menu-item-id since multiple 'add menu item'
```

, and data?

thx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find an element based on its attribute as well as its text, you will need to locate it via xpath. The following xpath will locate a button element that had the specified data-menu-item-id attribute and text:

```
//button[@data-menu-item-id="50" and text()="add menu item"]
```

You can get the element like this:

```
button = page.first(:xpath, '//button[@data-menu-item-id="50" and text()="add menu item"]')
```

And then click it like this:

```
button.click
```

Comment: '//button[@data-menu-item-id="50" and text()="add menu item"]' causes capybara 2.1 to crash